# Why is the Picard group of a smooth projective curve over a number field finitely generated?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

I've been trying to understand a paper which basically states that the Picard group of a smooth projective curve over a number field is finitely generated. The only thing I found on the internet is [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822095/picard-group-of-a-smooth-projective-curve) on this site supporting this assertion without proof. I'm looking for a proof ever since without success.

Furthermore, the paper claims that this follows from the Mordell-Weil Theorem, but isn't the Mordell-Weil Theorem about abelian varieties and rational points? I don't see any connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a smooth projective curve $C$ of genus $\geq 1$ over a number field $K$. Since we have an exact sequence

$$ 0 \rightarrow \text{Pic}^0(C) \rightarrow \text{Pic}(C) \rightarrow \text{NS}(C) \rightarrow 0,$$

it suffices to show that $\text{Pic}^0(C)$ and $\text{NS}(C)$ are finitely generated.

A [famous result](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZePysv04D6oC&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=neron-severi%20theorem&source=bl&ots=n6obePZ1Ej&sig=m4QxTsqVtqb77U8XfbSIftY38t4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuqsu016PRAhUG7YMKHUXZBuIQ6AEIMTAG#v=onepage&q=neron-severi%20theorem&f=false) says that the Néron-Severi group, $\text{NS}(C)$, is finitely generated.

Being an abelian variety over a number field, $\text{Pic}^0(C)$ is finitely generated by Mordell-Weil.

Comment: I don't think you need to do the base-change step. $\operatorname{Pic}^0(C)$ is an abelian variety over $K$, regardless of whether $C(K)$ is empty or not.

Comment: @Nefertiti of course! I was being unnecessarily careful. I've edited it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a generalization of the Mordell-Weil Theorem, which is as follows:

**Theorem** (Mordell-Weil-Lang-Neron) *Let $K$ be a field that is of finite type over its prime field (where the prime field is either $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb F_p$), and let $A/K$ be an abelian variety. Then $A(K)$ is finitely generated.*

The proof can be found in Lang's *Fundamentals of Diophantine Geometry*. We can chose $K$ as a number field to obtain the [Mordell-Weil theroem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell%E2%80%93Weil_theorem) for an abelian variety $A$ over a number field $K$. This yields the claim concerning the Picard group via the Jacobian, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226525/is-pic0x-of-a-curve-of-genus-geq-1-over-a-non-algebraically-closed-field) at MO. There also is a discussion that for some fields $Pic^0(X)$ may not be finitely-generated.